# Standard vs Standard Price Book

Tags: pricebook, product

What is the difference between Standard and Standard Price Book? I am quite confused why there are two price books by default.

[image]

Comment: I just didn't get your point. Are you asking about "Standard" and "Standard Price Book" objects in Sales Cloud? Actually, there are only 3 standard objects connected to Pricebooks in the platform: Pricebook2, PricebookEntry and Pricebook2History. Only 1 Pricebook2 object in an Org can be set to IsStandard flag, however. [Docs 1](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_products.htm), [Docs2](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_pricebook2.htm)

Comment: I added an image for reference @Eduard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one without the "Is Standard Price Book" checkbox checked is actually a custom price book. I know that some templates come with this extra price book built in for whatever reason, but it bears no special significance. It can be deleted like any custom price book, unlike the standard price book, which may never be deleted (though it can be deactivated).

Comment: I see. I am just surprised why it is named "Standard" and is in my org by default. I also haven't read about 'Standard' in the SF documentations.

Comment: @MiczDomz Yeah, you may as well delete it. It's not needed for anything, and is just as likely to confuse your users as it has you.